# c# XAML multiple binding in ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-phone-8.1

I'm still having a lot of trouble to properly understand binding in XAML on windows phone 8.1 and papers on MSDN don't really seem to help me.

I have two structures. One that fills the data inside the `ListBox` which already works great and one, that should set the color, which I don't really understand on how to do that.

My code so far looks like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Margin="5" Width="Auto" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <Border x:Name="BorderTap" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15" Margin="0" Height="80" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top">
          <Border.BorderBrush>
             <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
              <GradientStop Color="{Binding borderStart}" Offset="0"/>
              <GradientStop Color="{Binding borderStart}" Offset="0.7"/>
              <GradientStop Color="{Binding borderEnd}" Offset="1"/>
             </LinearGradientBrush>
           </Border.BorderBrush>
           <Border.Background>
              <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                  <GradientStop Color="{Binding boxStart}" Offset="0"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="{Binding boxStart}" Offset="0.7"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="{Binding boxEnd}" Offset="1"/>
              </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Grid>
               <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,0,0,0" Height="120" Width="120" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="Assets/due.png" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="0.4" />
            <Grid>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
               <StackPanel Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
               <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto">
                  <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="51" Margin="0" Width="51" Source="Assets/fish.png" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="2.307,0.881" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
               </StackPanel>
               <StackPanel Width="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Width="Auto" Margin="0" Orientation="Vertical">
                   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="0,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="19" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding URL}" Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF0097FF"/>
                 </StackPanel>
               </StackPanel>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

and the `structures` like this:

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public object Value { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Text;
  }
}

public class ColorContainer
{
  public string boxStart { get; set; }
  public string boxEnd { get; set; }
  public string borderStart { get; set; }
  public string borderEnd { get; set; }
  public string firstEntry { get; set; }
  public string secondEntry { get; set; }
}
```

How can I set the colors? Or where do I define them and update them?
And second question: After that, how can I select a value and add then another information from a third structure?

Thank you very much in advande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of GradientStop.Color is `Color`, so you need to define ColorContainer.boxStart as Color, or you need a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert string into Color, but to keep it simple, I will not use Converter since that adds more complexity to the code.

```
public class ColorContainer
{
    public Color boxStart { get; set; }
    public Color boxEnd { get; set; }
}
```

And I add a ColorContainer property to `ComboboxItem`.

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object URL { get; set; }
    public ColorContainer CContainer { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

And I define a `MyDataContext` class which contain the list of `ComboboxItem`s for binding

```
public class MyDataContext
{
    public MyDataContext()
    {
        ColorContainer _cContainer = new ColorContainer(); ;
        _cContainer.boxStart = Colors.Orange;
        _cContainer.boxEnd = Colors.Green;

        //note that all items use this _cContainer instance
        _items = new ObservableCollection<ComboboxItem>();
        _items.Add(new ComboboxItem() { Name = "name1", URL = "url1", CContainer = _cContainer });
        _items.Add(new ComboboxItem() { Name = "name2", URL = "url2", CContainer = _cContainer });
    }

    ObservableCollection<ComboboxItem> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<ComboboxItem> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
    }
}
```

Finally, the binding code:

```
<Border.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="{Binding CContainer.boxStart}" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop  Color="{Binding CContainer.boxStart}" Offset="0.7"/>
        <GradientStop  Color="{Binding CContainer.boxend}" Offset="1.0"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Border.Background>
```

Don't forget the set the DataContext of the page, as you already did.

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.DataContext = new MyDataContext();
    // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
    //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
}
```

**Update**

to fix the problem in your comment regarding the width of the listboxitem, add this

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Margin="5" Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
    <!--add this-->
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!--end-->
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        ....
```

Comment: A thank you, it worked! This Binding still confuses me very much.

Comment: Now it just messes with the width, it's all set to Auto and therefore the Border has the exact width, that is used by `Image` and `TextBlock`. While testing without being in the `DataTemplate` Environment, everything was OK. Any idea why this happens?